# Is $\lim_{a \to \infty}\sup_{n} \ n P(\sqrt{n}|X_n-\mu| > a)$ finite or infinite? Can it be made finite with assumptions on $\{X_n\}$?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\overline X_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, where $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ is a set of iid continuous random variables. For all $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n-\mu| > \varepsilon) = 0.
$$
Now, let $a > 0$ and consider the expression
$$
\lim_{a \to \infty}\sup_{n} \ n P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n-\mu| > a)
$$
Is this expression finite or infinite?

Intuitively speaking, as far as I can see, for any given $a$, when $n$ grows, the $n$ in front is going to $\infty$, but this is counteracted by the $P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n-\mu| > a)$ that goes to zero. So which wins out?

If it is infinite can we make any assumptions on the random variable $X$ such that the expression is then finite?

Comment: This question probably needs more information to get the answer to the question you're really after. Pick your favorite function $f(n)$ with $f(n) \to 0$ and let $P(X_n = 0) = 1- 2f(n), P(X_n = 1) = f(n), P(X_n = - 1) = f(n)$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Then for any $a$ and all sufficiently large $n$, $P(\sqrt{n}|X_n|>a) = 2f(n)$. The thing you're after might go to zero, it might go to infinity, it might  stay bounded. It all just depends on your pick of $f(n)$.

Comment: Ok, we can assume $X_n$ is the sample mean for a set of iid random variables for the sake of example. I will edit that assumption into the post.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian What about concentration inequalities for sums of iid random variables? These provide exponential decay. I've been doing some searching and it seems like it might be possible to bound the probability with using one of these inequalities.

Comment: Faster decay only happens when you go out further into the tail. For questions like this, it is usually best to keep representative examples in mind (in fact, I should have done this earlier since I mis-estimated in my head). If all of the $X_i$s are standard normal, then $P(\sqrt{n}|\bar{X}_n|>a) = P(|N(0,1)|>a )$, so the inner probability is order 1. If you want to see exponential decay, you would want to look at probabilities of the form $P(|\bar{X}_n - \mu|>a)$.

Comment: It occurs to me that I probably confused things a bit earlier so let me just summarize. The CLT tells you that $P(\sqrt{n}|\bar{X}_n - \mu|>a)$ is going to converge to $P(|N(0,\sigma^2)|>a)>0$ if the random variables have finite variance $\sigma^2$. Multiplying by $n$ and taking a supremum will then make the inner supremum infinite. If they don't have finite variance, then the probability will still be bounded from below and so the supremum is still infinite for each $a$. Concentration will help you if you replace $\sqrt{n}$ by something which grows slower.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see now the probability is indeed $O(1)$. I can't change the $\sqrt{n}$ but instead I can reasonably assume the $X_i$ are bounded random variables.

Comment: With bounded R.V.s, [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) says that $P(|\overline X_n - \mu| \ge t) = O(e^{-n^2t})$. And also that $P(n|\overline X_n - \mu| \ge t) = O(e^{-t^2})$ (this is $S_n$ on the Wikipedia page). Now I am interested in $P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n - \mu| \ge t)$ which is 'between' those two cases. It seems that we get $P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n - \mu| \ge t) = O(e^{-nt^2})$. Do you agree? That is, assuming the random variables are bounded would make $
\lim_{a \to \infty}\sup_{n} \ n P(\sqrt{n}|\overline X_n-\mu| > a)$ finite?

Comment: The central limit theorem still applies, even if (in fact, just more so) the $X_i$ are bounded.

Comment: @sonicboom Move the $\sqrt{n}$ to the other side of the equation. The result is $P(\sqrt{n}|\bar{X}_n - \mu| \geq t) =P(|\bar{X}_n - \mu| \geq t/\sqrt{n}) = O(e^{-n (t/\sqrt{n})^2}) = O(e^{-t^2})$, which is O(1) for $t$ fixed. There are no assumptions on the random variables that will make the probability you want decay. As noted above, the CLT still works for bounded random variables. Don't forget the denominator in the exponent in Hoeffding by the way, which is on the order of $n$.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Ok I see where I went wrong now, there is an $n^2$ in the exponent on the rhs of $P(|\overline X_n - \mu| \ge t) = e^{-\frac{2n^2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n(b_i - a_i)^2}}$, but it is countered by the sum over $n$ elements in the denominator.